# spark streaming with kafka one consumer is reading the data

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using the spark steaming using the kafka i have a topic with 20 partitions. When streaming job runs only one consumer is reading the data from all the topics which leads to slow in reading the data. Is there a way can we configure one consumer per partion in spark steaming.

```
JavaStreamingContext jsc = AnalyticsContext.getInstance().getSparkStreamContext();
Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = MessageSessionFactory.getConsumerConfigParamsMap(MessageSessionFactory.DEFAULT_CLUSTER_IDENTITY, consumerGroup);

String[] topics = topic.split(",");
Collection<String> topicCollection = Arrays.asList(topics);
metricStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                            jsc,
                            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                            ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topicCollection, kafkaParams)
);
}
```

---

```
TOPIC             PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
metric_data_spark 16         3379403197      3379436869      33672           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 7          3399030625      3399065857      35232           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 13         3389008901      3389044210      35309           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 17         3380638947      3380639928      981             consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 1          3593201424      3593236844      35420           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 8          3394218406      3394252084      33678           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 19         3376897309      3376917998      20689           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 3          3447204634      3447240071      35437           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 18         3375082623      3375083663      1040            consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 2          3433294129      3433327970      33841           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 9          3396324976      3396345705      20729           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 0          3582591157      3582624892      33735           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 14         3381779702      3381813477      33775           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 4          3412492002      3412525779      33777           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 11         3393158700      3393179419      20719           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 10         3392216079      3392235071      18992           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 15         3383001380      3383036803      35423           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 6          3398338540      3398372367      33827           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 12         3387738477      3387772279      33802           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
metric_data_spark 5          3408698217      3408733614      35397           consumer-2-da278f31-c368-414c-925b-d3ca4881709e /xx.xx.xx.xx    consumer-2
```

What changes we need to do make one consumer/per partition to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the consistent placement strategy, it should distribute over executors

When you run a Spark submit, you need to specify that you want at most 20 executors to be started. `--num-executors 20`

If you do more than that, though, you'll have idle executors not consuming Kafka data (but they might still be able to process other stages)

Comment: Hmm. Well, that's the only way I can think of... Are there just idle executors in the Spark UI when you do this?